# How to secure my app if the mobile device is stolen/lost

Tags: java, android

I am making a secure application which should not run if the mobile device is stolen/lost, or the sim card is changed. If I programatically uninstall my app it prompts user whether she wants to uninstall it or not. I want this thing in a hidden way.

One more thing is to keep a file in assets/raw folder and when sim card is changed i must remove that file and my app will not run without that file. But deleting the files from both folders is not possible on run time.

All suggestions highly appreciated!

I know about password protection, cryptography, Pro-Guard, Dex-Guard, keep minimum functionality on phone. Guys I must need a way to remove the App! Please help on that point

Thankx in advance!

Comment: how about making the app password protected, so it is not accessible to others?

Comment: Have you looked at android's Device Admin Api ? you could use that to have control  over device.

Comment: Get an RF chip installed under your skin and the program will only operate within range of your RF id. :D ( this is a joke )

Comment: Password protection is already there. We want to protect the source code as well

Comment: Can i use the device admin api to remove my app from android?

Answer (score 3):

One more secure [solution](http://www.nubosoftware.com/howItWorks.html) is to run your app on some Android x86 servers and to pipe in only the user interface to the phone.

[image: http://www.nubosoftware.com/images/howItWorks.png]

**Disclaimer:** I've never used those guys, so I don't know how good they are. I just saw their lightning talk presentation at the most recent AnDevCon in San Francisco, and I just thought it was a clever idea.

One added advantage that this solution provides is that your employee's personal content doesn't get mixed in with the content of your company's. In hindsight, it's an old solution that has worked quite well for PCs and remote workers.

Comment: Well we already have the architecture like this. user interface and some business logic will reside on Android rest on desktop. but still how to remove the app :-)

Comment: No, I guarantee you that you do not have something like this!! This guy's lightning demo showed a fully functional android UI on an old iPhone. Think of it as a remote VNC session to an instance of Android running somewhere else on some x86 server (but with touch and keyboard events being piped over to the server instance). The data connection goes down, or the phone gets stolen and turned off by a thief right away, or the phone gets put inside a faraday envelope to avoid it phoning home, and the projected UI to the Android instance goes away simply because the data connection gets cut off. :)

Comment: Well if your are talking about some thing like Remote Desktop then we have tried that as well. It is not good enough, response time is slow. Even then I will look deeply into your proposed solution. Thankx!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you are asking for, but it may address your concerns.  In general, the big concern with a stolen phone would be data.  If you are concerned about someone else running your application, it seems that authentication should address that.  A secondary concern is that someone could de-compile your code to learn details that could lead to exploitation.  So here are 2 suggestions that address these concerns.

1. Use Progaurd to obfuscate your code.  That way if the device is rooted and the APK is obtained, it cannot be de-complied (at least not into easily understandable code).  [Reference](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html).
2. If you store any data in a database on the device, be sure to encrypt it.  SQLCipher is a free library that will allow you to do so.  [Reference](http://sqlcipher.net/sqlcipher-for-android/).

Comment: Yup I know about Pro-Guard. But it just improves the level of security. my main emphasis is some how to delete the app from android device. Thanks for your suggestion

Answer (score 1):

Answering some other interesting comments I was pinged about:
A couple of things:

1. I am that guy who gave the lightning talk in AnDevCon Stephan Branczyk mentioned, but I'm not a heavy stackoverflow user so I do not have the privilege to reply. 50 Upvotes for  this comment and I may be able to answer inline :)
2. I will however give my insights on this, so if you are "paranoid" about security and want to read more about it from the founder of a "paranoid security vendor" - you can continue reading it.
3. Otherwise goto 7.
4. It is very important to understand that there is no catch-all solution - so do not be naive about it. All Android security best practices are great - but up to some point, as your Operating System (ROM, MOD,...) can, and will be compromised. I do not want anyone to panic - but there is NO perfect solution.
5. Stephan is right about Nubo's security design concept - if you violate the terms - your are out of the game. If you're out of network, or doing something suspicious - well - the device is not in control, no matter what. We aim towards satisfying both the user in their personal space, and the IT managers in the remote Android space.
   It is very important for me to say clarify it is NOT a remote desktop. It's not even close to it - we have developed a Display protocol for Android from scratch - intended for the mobile environment. This is nothing like Remote Desktop/X11/VNC/... for "PC".
6. Should you need a "perfect" solution, you need to have a "trusted" device, which involves hard-core hardware support + secure bootloader + block verification chains etc. You can learn from the ChromeOS project if you are interested but I assume you are not willing to take it that far.
7. Answering the original answer: It depends on what phone. If you want
   to use the PackageManager - you need your app to have a System
   certificate, which means that unless you bundle it with your own
   device, or do other tricky stuff I will not get into in this post -
   you can't. What you can do is to use the BIND_DEVICE_ADMIN permission in your manifest,
   and essentially register your app as an administrator (Something like MDM, etc.). Then, with some more trickery stuff you can handle your problem on the nominal case. You could bundle another app with that capability, and just invoke it from your app if you want to be on the very safe side.

*This post is already way too long and referring to too many questions so if you have further questions please go ahead and ask. I will try to reply before 2014...

Comment: Well Thanks for your reply. I would like to know what you mean by trick stuff?? As you have stated:                                                        What you can do is to use the BIND_DEVICE_ADMIN permission in your manifest, and essentially register your app as an administrator (Something like MDM, etc.). Then, with some more trickery stuff you can handle your problem on the nominal case.

Comment: Actually  if you can provide some code snippet that would be more then best. I have requested NUBO trial version 2 weeks ago but they guys have not replied yet.

Comment: I'll just give the general picture of what's being done when you "# pm uninstall" from a (possibly rooted) shell.
Let's say you have two apps, A and B.B wants to uninstall A.
Should B have ADMIN permissions, it would be able to trigger the PackageManager's deletePackageAsUser() method, or something similiar. Yet, assuming you do not have System permission, you will need A and B to have the same uid (android:sharedUserId in the manifest).


`    IPackageManager proxyPmIPackageManager.Stub.asInterface(ServiceManager.getService("package"));`
    proxyPm.deletePackageAsUser(..);


I hope it helps.

Comment: As per your trial request,
Please PM me/send me an email < ron AT nubo's domain name >, and I will give you a hand with that.
You need to stand behind a domain name to engage with us though (I would happily share development version with you, but I would have to hire you for that first - and then you'll also see performance at another level).

** Sorry about the terrible formatting at the previous comment. Tried to edit with md, didn't go well and I had to run...

Comment: One more thing: If you use a shared user ID I think you don't need ADMIN policy at all.
As I said, there are tricky things, more than one way to do things, and there are slight chances that I would be able to give personal/ongoing support on it, so I hope you understand the basic direction.

Best,
Ron

Comment: Thanks for all your support. I will explore the details.

Answer (score 0):

step 1 : write a process to run in background

step 2 : make the process be active when cell starts

step 3 : check for internet connection or balance

step 4 : if internet available mail yourself phone specific details like IMEI ,MAC ,IP whatever you think is important ,

step 5 : locating GPS location would be very helpful

step 7 : recieve these mails from the mail id registered in your app

Comment: I cannot understand how your answer relates to my question :(